# Analyzing bitstreams using Icestorm

Tags: yosys

I'm trying to understand the bitstreams generated by Yosys/arachne-pnr as described on http://www.clifford.at/icestorm/:

> The recommended approach for learning how to use this documentation is to synthesize very simple circuits using Yosys and Arachne-pnr, run the icestorm tool `icebox_explain` on the resulting bitstream files, and analyze the results using the HTML export of the database mentioned above. `icebox_vlog` can be used to convert the bitstream to Verilog. The output file of this tool will also outline the signal paths in comments added to the generated Verilog code.

In order to understand the effect a change in the bitstream has, it would be helpful if I could change the `.ex` file and convert it back to an ASCII bitstream (instead of having to identify the bit manually) for uploading to the FPGA.  Is there a way to do so?

I'm a bit concerned about damaging the FPGA with an invalid bitstream.  Are there situations where this is known to happen? Is there a way to simulate a bitstream?

Also, it would be helpful to have some kind of “higher-level” explanation format which e.g. shows the IE/REN bits on the I/O blocks to which they correspond, not the one on which they have to be set in the bitstream. Is there such a format?

I know of the possibility to generate an equivalent Verilog circuit, but the problem with this is that it doesn't usually allow me a lossless round-trip back into a bitstream. Is there a way to generate an equivalent Verilog circuit which (e.g. by instantiating the blocks explicitly) yields the exact same bitstream when processed with Yosys/arachne-pnr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm a bit concerned about damaging the FPGA with an invalid bitstream. Are there situations where this is known to happen? Is there a way to simulate a bitstream?

I have not damaged any FPGA so far. (I have, however, managed to damage the serial flash on one icestick after running some test that reprogrammed it in a loop.)

But this does not mean that you cannot damage your FPGA by programming it with an invalid bitstream. You could theoretically configure the FPGA in a way that produces a driver-driver conflict. I don't know how well the hardware deals with something like that. I have not run any experiments to find out..

> Also, it would be helpful to have some kind of “higher-level” explanation format which e.g. shows the IE/REN bits on the I/O blocks to which they correspond, not the one on which they have to be set in the bitstream. Is there such a format?

`icebox_vlog` produces a higher-level output. But it does not output things like I/O blocks, so it might be too high-level for your needs.

> I know of the possibility to generate an equivalent Verilog circuit, but the problem with this is that it doesn't usually allow me a lossless round-trip back into a bitstream. Is there a way to generate an equivalent Verilog circuit which (e.g. by instantiating the blocks explicitly) yields the exact same bitstream when processed with Yosys/arachne-pnr?

Not at the moment. But it should not be too hard to extend `icebox_vlog` to provide this functionality. So if you really need that, it might be something within your reach to add yourself.